# tikz workbreakdown

Tags: tikz-styles

I need to improve workbreakdown in defining distance level between chapter, section, subsection, and subsubsection in a flexible way.  Your help is appreciated. Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{10pt}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,trees}

\tikzset{
  basic/.style  = {draw, text width=2cm, drop shadow, font=\sffamily, rectangle},
  root/.style   = {basic, rounded corners=2pt, thin, align=center, fill=green!30},
 level 2/.style={sibling distance=4cm, level distance=4.5cm, basic, rounded corners=6pt, thin,align=center, fill=green!60, text width=8em},
  level 3/.style = {node distance = 5cm and 2cm, basic, thin, align=left, fill=pink!60, text width=5.5em},
 level 4/.style = {basic, thin, align=right, fill=pink!30, text width=6.5em},
 level 5/.style = {basic, thin, align=right, fill=green!30, text width=6.5em}
}

    \begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[
level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm, level distance=1.5cm},
  edge from parent/.style={->,draw},
  >=latex]

% niveau1
\node[root] {book}
% niveau2
  child {node[level 2] (c1) {chapter 1}}
  child {node[level 2] (c2) {chapter 2}}
  child {node[level 2] (c3) {chapter3}}
  child {node[level 2] (c4) {chapter4}};

% section chapitre1
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={level 3}]
\node [below of = c1, xshift=15pt, yshift=0pt] (c11) {Section};
\node [below of = c11] (c12) {Section};
\node [below of = c12] (c13) {Section};

% section chapitre2
\node [below of = c2, xshift=15pt, yshift=0pt] (c21) {Section};
\node [below of = c21] (c22) {Section};
\node [below of = c22] (c23) {Section};
\node [below of = c23] (c24) {Section};

% Subsection chapitre2
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={level 4}]
\node [below right of = c21, xshift=5pt, yshift=-7pt] (c211) {Subsection};
\node [below of = c211] (c212) {Subsection};
\node [below of = c212] (c213) {Subsection};
\node [below of = c213] (c214) {Subsection};

\node [below right of = c22, xshift=5pt, yshift=0pt] (c221) {Subsection};
\node [below of = c221] (c222) {Subsection};
\node [below of = c222] (c223) {Subsection};
\node [below of = c223] (c224) {Subsection};
 level 4/.style = {basic, thin, align=right, fill=pink!30, text width=6.5em}
\end{scope}

% Subsubsection chapitre2
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={level 5}]
\node [below right of = c211, xshift=5pt, yshift=-7pt] (c2111) {Subsubsection};
\node [below of = c2111] (c2112) {Subsubsection};
\end{scope}


% section chapitre3
\node [below of = c3, xshift=15pt, yshift=0pt] (c31) {Section};
\node [below of = c31] (c32) {Section};
\node [below of = c32] (c33) {Section};


% section chapitre4
\node [below of = c4, xshift=15pt, yshift=0pt] (c41) {Section};
\node [below of = c41] (c42) {Section};
\node [below of = c42] (c43) {Section};
\node [below of = c43] (c44) {Section};
\node [below of = c44] (c45) {Section};
\end{scope}



% lines from each level 1 node to every one of its "children"
\foreach \value in {1,2,3}
  \draw[->] (c1.195) |- (c1\value.west);

\foreach \value in {1,...,4}
  \draw[->] (c2.195) |- (c2\value.west);

\foreach \value in {1,...,3}
  \draw[->] (c3.195) |- (c3\value.west);

\foreach \value in {1,...,5}
  \draw[->] (c4.195) |- (c4\value.west);

\foreach \value in {1,...,4}
  \draw[->] (c21.195) |- (c21\value.west);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you give more detail as to what what you mean by "improve workbreakdown in defining distance level between chapter, section, subsection, and subsubsection in a flexible way" ? Possibly I am slow, but it is not at all clear to me what you what to improve and in what ways (hopefully objective) ways that you want to do this.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

Apart from the top part of the diagram, you are not drawing the structure as a tree but placing the nodes manually, which is never going to be a very flexible solution. Using any of the tree-drawing approaches - built-in, the `trees` library, `tikz-qtree`, `forest` etc. - will make for more flexible, more concise and easier to maintain code.

If Forest is an option, you can allow the package to layout the tree automatically in most cases. Forest does a good job of constructing compact trees which avoid overlapping while minimising white space. The `edges` library provides a `folder` style for the main body of the tree and styles can be applied automatically by `level`. Note that the root node is at level zero and the chapters at level one, in this case. It also means that the tree can be specified extremely concisely.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\tikzset{% note the change to the level numbering: root -> level 0, level 2 -> level 1 etc.
  basic/.style = {draw, text width=2cm, drop shadow, font=\sffamily},
  level 0/.style = {basic, rounded corners=2pt, thin, align=center, fill=green!30},
  level 1/.style={basic, rounded corners=6pt, thin,align=center, fill=green!60, text width=8em},
  level 2/.style = {basic, thin, align=left, fill=pink!60, text width=5.5em},
  level 3/.style = {basic, thin, align=right, fill=pink!30, text width=6.5em},
  level 4/.style = {basic, thin, align=right, fill=green!30, text width=6.5em}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  where level>=1{folder, grow'=0, fit=band}{},
  for tree={
    node options/.process={Ow{level}{level #1}},
    s sep'+=5pt,
  },
  [book
    [chapter 1
      [Section] [Section] [Section]
    ]
    [chapter 2
      [Section
        [Subsection
          [Subsubsection]
          [Subsubsection]
        ]
        [Subsection]
        [Subsection]
        [Subsection]
     ] 
      [Section
        [Subsection]
        [Subsection]
        [Subsection]
        [Subsection]
      ] 
      [Section] 
      [Section]
    ]
    [chapter 3
      [Section] [Section] [Section]
    ]
    [chapter 4
      [Section] [Section] [Section] [Section] [Section]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Forest version]

Comment: That's cool! Didn't know about `forest`.

Comment: ("C:\Users\gateway\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pgf\libraries\
pgflibraryfadings.code.tex")))
No file wb.aux.
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
("C:\Users\gateway\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.
mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgf@temp.
<to be read again>

Comment: Forest is very good but I get the message sent already.

Comment: @HoudaAraj What version of Forest do you have? I'm using '2017/07/14 v2.1.5'. The end of the error message may give you more information. It should at least give a line number, although the line number isn't always very helpful.

Comment: Do you get an error with exactly the code I posted, pasted into an empty `.tex` file in a clean directory? Or do you only get an error when you try to integrate the code into your document?

Comment: I have 2.03 15 April 2016 for Forest. When I try to update Miketex respond cannot update. I will try later. Pasted in an empty clean directory.

Comment: When Forest updated it was fine. Many thanks. Houda

Comment: @HoudaAraj Thanks for letting me know. Otherwise, I could have tried to adapt it backwards, but I'm not sure I've got 2.03 any more. Some code got broken by bug fixes because it originally had to compensate for bugs and some new code won't work without allowing for the older bugs with older versions. (Your error looked like such a case because of the complaint about the invalid thing. Some of those definitely got fixed by incremental updates since 2.03.) Anyway, now you have all the available fixes :-).